# flexbox fallback to display table in older browsers

Tags: flexbox

Is there a better way than below to ensure that I only target browsers that don't support flexbox. I think this could work, but maybe I'll need some styles only for ie8 and 9 for example that might affect modern browsers too. Would it be best to create a separate stylesheet altogether?

```
.flex{
  display:table;
  display:flex;

  .column{
    display:table-cell;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: All modern browsers support flexbox, except IE < 10 ([source](http://caniuse.com/#search=Flex)). If you want fallback HTML for IE8 and 9, try [IE conditional comments](https://www.google.com/search?q=Microsoft+internet+explorer+conditional+statements&oq=Microsoft+internet+explorer+conditional+statements&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.30700j0j4&client=ms-android-att-us&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#q=internet+explorer+conditional+comments).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The long answer is complicated. The good thing is that IE10 and most older browsers in use today, support flexbox. But an old syntax with a quite different spec and behavior. See [flexbox support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) table. I also suggest you have a look and/or use this [tool](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) with the *Generate legacy flexbox styles* checkbox enabled to get an idea of what's involved. It will give you a fairly cross compatible CSS syntax to use.

If you care about cross-compatiblity with older browsers as you should*, `display:flex;` alone is not recommended. You need to add those old flexbox prefixes. As for IE8 and 9, you can use a table fallback indeed targeting IE8 desktop browsers if you must. Which comes to the following rule set:

```
.flex-container {
  display: table;        /* IE < 10, Opera *Presto* Desktop (Now dead) */
  display: -webkit-box;  /* Safari 3.1 - 6, Chrome < 21 (2009 Spec), UCBrowser Android */
  display: -moz-box;     /* Firefox 2 - 27 (2009 Spec), UCMini Android */
  display: -ms-flexbox;  /* IE10 (2012 Syntax) */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari 6.1 - 8, Android < 4.4, BB < 10, Chrome 21 - 28 */
  display: flex;         /* Edge 12+, Firefox 28+, Blink, Safari 9+, Opera Mini 8+ */
}
```

Noting that the main feature differences between new and old flexbox spec and [support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27416556/1647538) is the lack of `flex-wrap`. So besides the many ["flexbugs"]  (https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) and differences to watch for. Keep in mind that you **cannot** use `flex-wrap` if you want extensive backward compatibility beyond 2012 browsers or IE9.

*It's also worth noting that if your target users are in Asia or Africa, you will definitely need the `-webkit-box` model for the UCBrowser for Android, which currently still doesn't support the new syntax. (As of 2016, UCBrowser has over 10% of mobile browser usage worldwide and 25% in Asia). `-moz-box` is arguably also needed for UCMini which is based on older Firefox (usage data and whereabouts is publicly unknown however).

For the flex items `table-cell` or `table-row` fallbacks. It gets tricky, especially with flexbox nesting.

However, there are 3 options available:

1) Use feature detection with a script like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs). And use the Modernizr CSS document styling to declare the IE8-9 fallback rules via JS feature detection. Like this:

```
html.no-flexbox .flex-item {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

2) Use IE CSS conditional styling:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-8-9-fallbacks.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

OR

3) The other no-JS way is using [CSS hacks](http://browserhacks.com/). With a display value which will ignored by other browsers, and only be parsed and applied by IE8-9.

With: a)

```
.flex-item {
  display: block;
  display: table-cell\0/; /*IE8-10 */
}
```

and/or:
b)

```
@media \0screen\,screen\9 { /* IE6-10 and exclude FF2 */
  .flex-item { display: table-cell; }
}
```